# Compatibility issue of android application with os version 4.4.2

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have uploaded my android application on google play store with minimum sdk version 19 which is 4.4
However, on a android tablet with os version 4.4.2 it show app is not compatible with this version. Application is getting downloaded on 4.4.4.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      package="com.abc"
>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"/>

<application
    android:name=".application.abc"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name_by_flavor"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_abc"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="ManifestResource">

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name_by_flavor"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"
        >
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name_by_flavor">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>
```

Can anyone help what might be the possible problem

Comment: I think that there is a problem in your manifest file.

Comment: Share your manifest file.

Comment: Added manifest...removed some activities

Comment: `removed some activities` did you remove anything else? `<uses-feature>`?

Comment: No i have not removed anything else